# Fetching a public page's posts doesn't work while it works in other pages

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

For a project, I need to get some public pages' posts.
 I have 105 pages I need to get posts from and my program works fine with the most of them, but not with one.

When I use my app's access token it gets me what I want, except when trying to get posts from one page, "Yaakov.Perry".
When I send a request to this page, the server sends me this error:

```
 "error": {
"message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'Yaakov.Perry' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
```

Also, while my app's access token works for every page except this, the access code that the graph api explorer generates works for every one (including it).
Does any one know why this problem happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like you are just wrong about that being a public page. `https://www.facebook.com/Yaakov.Perry` only shows me “Sorry, this content isn't available right now. The link you followed may have expired, or the page may only be visible to an audience you're not in.”

Comment: the access token from the api explorer may be a user token, not an app token. make sure you understand the difference, the page may be restricted by age or location. an app token is not bound to any user, so facebook does not know if you are allowed to see the content with an app token.